# df[column].mean() returns a float number, how do I check if it is different from zero in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

`df[column].mean()` returns a float number, how do I check if it is different from zero in Python?
Do I have to include all the decimals or is `df[column].mean() == 0` fine?

Comment: In Python, `0.0 == 0` is true.  Most other languages too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too trivial to be helpful to a general audience.

Comment: Its a very trivial doubt.. if you have tried it yourself you could have found it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python understands the value of zero in this case. You may do that:

```
df[column].mean() == 0
```

Example:

```
0.000 == 0
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works unless the difference from zero d is:

```
d<1e-323
```

That's at least my result for the ipython3.8.2 I use in my console.